# SQL: table with 10 fields which contain ids from other tables or 0 (inner or left join to "read" the table?)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a db with 11 tables.

The `tables A` contains 15 fields, 10 of theirs contain an id from another table or the 0 value.
Each of these tables has two fields, `id` and `description`.

I would to query the db to obtain the `table A` with the right `description` at the place of the id or null if the id is 0.

What do I have to use? join, left or inner join? how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this statement to select description & use left join of rest of the tables with tablea:

```
IF(id = 0, NULL, description)
```

Example:

```
SELECT A.* , IF(A.bid = 0, NULL, B.description) , IF(A.cid = 0, NULL, C.description) 
from tablea A 
LEFT JOIN tableb B on A.bid = B.id 
LEFT JOIN tablec C on A.cid = C.id
```

and so on....

Comment: how can I do the left join for all the other fields?

Comment: As displayed in answer do same changes for all other fields

Answer (score 0):

Left join

```
SELECT * FROM A 
    LEFT JOIN B ON (A.KEY=B.KEY)
```

and you get Null when the join isn't possible

Comment: how can I do the left join for all the other fields?

Comment: Make 10 left joins and you will get 10 registers. After this you will have to group the data to convert 10 registers to 1